# compile dynamic vue.js content added via ajax call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue.js 2.0 and have a problem.

I have a custom component which is loaded with the page, but the element that uses the component isn't used until a button is pressed, at that point the HTML is loaded and added to the DOM in a slide panel (whose content is dynamic).

Edit: It might be usuful to know the slide panel is dynamicly created using the jquery-slidepanel plugin... meaning I can't put a a placeholer in it like this:

```
<div id="slidePanel">
  <component v-bind:is="test-thing">
    <DYNAMIC CONTENT>
  </component>
</div>
```

My problem is the instead on the component rendering the new content correctly I just see the {{ someitem }} all over the place.

here is a jsFiddle demonstrating what I am talking about: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/StuartMc77/5vqg7uyc/)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots will help you.

Comment: you have to put the html content into the component template and keep in the html this element <div id="app"></div>

Comment: @boussadjra - could you update the jsfiddle so I can see what you mean?

Comment: the use of jquery makes some confusion, and i you have decided to use Vue.js you will not need to jquery because there's a lot of vue plugins and components can do the same thing

Comment: Please ignore the jquery... I only used that to append the content to the element and could have done it with just JS... in the actual app the content of the slide panel is loaded with an AJAX call that returns the HTML to be inserted.

Comment: i understand what you want to get but i think you can't do that because the reactivity and the life cycle your component can't detect your data

Comment: @StuartMc you can fix your fiddle (like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/2k7jq9ow/)) by using component appending (solution found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-append-a-component-to-the-dom)), but i don't know if it fits to your project

Comment: Close but not quite... thank you though... I think I will have to take this a different direction for now.